# Revertive SMS from Nokia mobile to MAC

Tags: macos, sms, at-command, nokia-s40

I want to read sms from My nokia mobile through java application,mobile is connected to Mac via usb I have tried AT-commands 
,I can send sms ,But can't read them
I have noika 6303 S40 series phone.
there is something Called PC suite sdk but not available for mac 
also there is a Application called SyncMate it Shows sms in my inbox So I know it is possible on mac........
Please Help Me out I want just to read sms from inbox of my mobile to My java Application